# Android - strange app Heap behavior

Tags: android, memory-management

I measure acutal allocated RAM of my Application by DDMS and it's cause GC, which shows actual allocated RAM.

I have made simple project of activities, which goes one by one. Here is status of memory allocation (in MB):

> ---->    I am opening activities

Begin > 2,258 > 2,305 > 2,335 > 2,366 > 2,390 > 2,419 > 2,441 > 2,472 > 2,496

And now I go back to the first activity:

```
                     I am closing activities        <----
```

...End < 2,315 < 2,318 < 2,340 < 2,370 < 2,392 < 2,423 < 2,445 < 2,477

My results - despite I have returned back to the starting point of my app, there is about 60kB bigger allocated space? Why so? I am certain, when I try open more intens this way and then close them, the difference would be bigger. Does my App holds at the ...End point still some "traces" of references to last activities?

Thx

Comment: Probably yes. If you have some time, I recommend the "Memory management for Android Apps" session from the last google IO. There are some good explanations and ways to profile this behavior mentioned. http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html

Comment: Thanks... I will certainly look at it, do you know, is there any way how to force and app to release sources (clean it!s heap)?

Comment: You can invoke `System.gc()`. But thats a) just a hint to the garbage collector, not a command and b) usually not wise because it takes often more than one run of the gc to actually free resources. Also c) it's basically messing with androids memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to release all references in the ondestroy method of your activities.